# Random UK registration plate generator

Tags: php, arrays, regex, random

I want to create a function that generates a random UK vehicle registration plate (using the structure introduced in 2001) but really don't know where to start.

All plates follow the structure:

[two letters][two digits][3 random letters]

e.g. BD51 SMR

More information on the structure can be found here: http://goo.gl/jh8Ldi

The first two letters represent an area code of which there are a few hundred and it's not as simple as A + A-Z, B + A-Z etc etc. For example A can then be followed by any letter except I, Q and Z, whereas D can only be followed by letters A-K (excluding i).

The two number represent the year of manufacture - I think I'm fine on this one.

The final three letters I can deal with.

Is there anyway of getting the first two letters without having to list all possible outcomes in an array?

Thanks

Comment: It might be possible to get the first two letters without an explicit list of values, but you'll need to tell us what the algorithm is for generating them.

Comment: I don't think there's another way to do this. You're always going to need to be able to check what you've got is a valid result, whether that's by a lookup or very complex rules in the code. Depending on what you're using this for - does it need to be truly random? It looks like a few of the initial letters let you have a second letter from A-Y, so if you're prepared to sacrifice some possibilities, you can make something that's less complicated, by just choosing from those.

Comment: `D` Dees Shrewsbury `L M N O P R S T U V W X Y`

Answer (score 1):

```
Is there anyway of getting the first two letters without having to list all possible outcomes in an array?
```

Well, yes. You can encode the rules as shown in the Wikipedia tables - it's A-Z (with some exclusions) followed by A-Y (with different exclusions) but then some exceptions (e.g. X only has A-F following it).

But why not use an array? The wikipedia page lists them all out for you, it's only a few mins work to turn that into an array, and then you don't need to work out what the best way of encoding it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think this text from the indicated "Vehicle Registration..." page is the key to answering your question:

```
In addition to the above local memory tags, personalised registrations are also offered
with arbitrary "local memory tags" prefixes, except for the letters I, Q, and Z.
```

If I read this correctly then the letter D *can* be followed by any letter except I, Q, and Z, *if* somebody requests (and is granted) such a local memory tag. In which case all you need to do in order to generate a random local memory tag is write a function f() which chooses a positive integer at random from 1 to 23, and then call it twice, mapping each number to a letter:

```
1->A
2->B
...
8->H    // skip I
9->J
10->K
...
15->P   // skip Q
16->R
17->S
...
23->Y   // skip Z
```